# What are the disadvantages of using an excel worksheet instead of a csv with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm making my own simple spreadsheet for a, "note card," program. Basically, I have an excel spreadsheet with two columns: Question, Answer. The idea is that the program presents the question, you give your answer, and then check if you're correct. Just like you would with handwritten note cards.

I'm creating the note card dataset in excel, and in order to maintain excel formatting I've been saving files with the extension xlsx. Now, I'm writing the code as such:

```
pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

What are the downfalls to this approach? I notice the extreme file size differential between csv and xlsx, but does this matter in small datasets? Is pandas significantly slower at reading excel spreadsheets?

I'm so used to CSVs in data analysis that it feels wrong using xlsx. Is this a non-issue?

Comment: The only problem with your program is that you overcomplicate things. People are really going too far with current `pandas` trend.


Answering your question - reading xls is slower, but like fraction of a second, so, who cares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the file sizes, reading excel files is also slower than csv since it saves the data formatting. However, this can be a trivial factor if your dataset is small.

The main question, you should be asking whether you need the excel data formatting for your system? If going with csv is an option, you should always go with it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I prefer having the excel formatting as it makes the spreadsheet legible the moment I open it, rather than having to, "format to fit width," every time I open the spreadsheet.